# return from function on event.target.value

Tags: function, return, event-listener

Could someone please help me understand why when I write my code for an event listener the code below gives me an error "color1 is not defined"?

```
let penColor = document.getElementById("color");
                penColor.addEventListener("change",chooseColor)
        function chooseColor(e){
            let color1 = e.target.value;
            return color1;
            
        };
```

However, when I change this code only slightly to ( below ) all works fine

```
   let penColor = document.getElementById("color");
        penColor.addEventListener("change",chooseColor)
        
        
        function chooseColor(e){
            return color1 =  e.target.value;
            
        };
```

I was expecting to get the color1 after change from the event listener